# Loading page contents into one page (Duplicated Content) bad for SEO?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress, seo

I'm building a page on my site (wordpress) where I am pulling in multiple **posts** of post type **people** (url: site.com/people/name-of-person) into a **page** called **people** (url: site.com/people) as a list. It is designed to be a list of people.

Now, What I am essentially doing is, in my list of people, I have a thumbnail of the person, upon clicking, the persons profile is displayed underneath via javascript. This is pulling in name, job position, favourite quote, details about them, some Instagram photos and a larger profile image. So you can quickly click through each persons profile, navigate around etc.

Now I'm thinking how to structure the page. In terms of the page by itself, does it makes more sense to have all the text for each person (title, job position etc) all loaded already into the page? BUT, this text will be an almost an exact dupe of the individual post for that person. (Which I don't intend to directly link to anywhere through the site, they will always be directed to /people)

Will this have a bad effect on SEO with this structure? With the duplicated content? Or should I not worry too much about this?

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Comment: I think its not wise to load all the details about the people cos it may slow down the loading time of the page and users with limited data or a slow data connection will have a tough time!!

Comment: Hey Shrikanth Buds, You're right, I shouldn't load in all the details as this will indeed increase page load.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming.

Comment: sorry @Shrikanth Buds, I accidentally submitted and ran out of time on my comment add :). You're right, I don't want to load too much content on page load. But, I want the content loaded to be meaningful. It's a list of people, so I was going to load in the text content for each person then load in the images upon clicking each person to save bandwidth there. Or I can load each person by AJAX. I'm just concerned about the use of Duplicated here

Comment: I added an answer if it satisfies your question vote it as an answer if it doesnt ..heres a better way to do it if you dont wanna make another page...when the user clicks on the person you automatically get the persons profile with ajax and post it...this way the data can be at the least when the user loads the page and will build up depending upon the users choice..  :D

Comment: Dont worry about the duplicates i dont think it does anything to your website..

Answer (score -1):

Loading the profile of the people obviously takes more time and make the page to load slowly .which in turn gives trouble for the users with very slow internet connection or users with limited data..
Instead of doing that just keep the data in the page minimal and when the user clicks on the thumbnail redirect them to another page where you can provide them the info about people...

OR

USE **AJAX**